# Dynamically building a sizeable DOM element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I need to be able to dynamically generate (and insert into the DOM) HTML elements that are quite sizeable such as the snippet below:

```
<div class="messageToAndFromOtherMember" id="13">
    <span>the message</span> 
    <span>2012-12-02 14:05:45.0</span> 
    <span>sent</span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="13" id="listOfMessagesForDeletion3" name="listOfMessagesForDeletion">
    <input type="hidden" name="_listOfMessagesForDeletion" value="on">
</div>
```

As of now I am not sure how to go about building such a large DOM element and do it following jQuery best practises. What I do now is simply concatenate a string as follows (which is quite ugly...):

```
        $("#latestMessages"+" "+"div[id^='"+response.senderId+'.'+response.recipientId+"'], #latestMessages"+" "+"div[id^='"+response.recipientId+'.'+response.senderId+"']").replaceWith("<div id='"+latestMessageId+"'><span>"+response.message+"</span><span>SENT</span><span><a href='"+response.recipientId+"'>ma conversation avec "+response.recipientId+"</a></span></div>");
```

I would be very grateful if someone could suggest a better way of building the DOM element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the child elements and apply your response data to them rather than concatenation. I presume there may be more than one message given the context of your snippet. In this case you can use templating to append each subsequent message div. I prefer the native template engine in knockoutjs for this, http://knockoutjs.com/ . There are plenty of other jquery templating solutions:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+templating

Comment: Thanks Jim! Knockout seems very relevant to what I want to achieve. However I am completely new to it. Can you please answer one last question: did you have in mind the KO templates as described [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) or something else in KO?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, the Native templating at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html is what i am referring to. I have an example at my blog where I am populating cascading select inputs using knockoutjs if that helps: http://jimfrenette.com/2012/10/jquery-mobile-cascaded-selects-using-mvc4-and-knockoutjs/ also, there are some great exapmles by Ryan Niemeyer on jsfiddle that helped me learn knockoutjs as well: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/08/all-of-knockoutjscom-live-samples-in.html